# ip tunnel of network 10.0.0.x (machine A) via 152.83 to machine B

Tags: networking, tunnel

I am trying to set up a tunnel 'gre'. THe setup is as follows. On machine A, I have two networks: 10.0.0.x (eth2) and 152.83.x.x (eth1). To machine A, I have connected other machines that share 10.0.0.x. Machine A has a static 10.0.0.10 address, other three machines connected to it are 10.0.0.1-10.0.0.3.

Now, I have a remote machine B that is on the same network 152.83.x.x (eth1). I am trying to bring over all IPs 10.0.0.x (e.g. 10.0.0.1-10).

I have done the following on machine A:

```
sudo ip tunnel add tunnel1 mode gre remote 152.83.70.180 local 152.83.70.114
sudo ip addr add 10.0.2.1 dev tunnel1
sudo ip link set tunnel1 up
sudo ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev tunnel1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

On machine B, I entered:

```
sudo ip tunnel add tunnel1 mode gre local 152.83.70.180 remote 152.83.70.114
sudo ip addr add 10.0.1.1 dev tunnel1
sudo ip link set tunnel1 up
sudo ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev tunnel1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

Now, when I ping from B the address 10.0.0.1 etc. I get no response. Moreover, even on network A, my tunnel1 somehow masks 10.0.0.1-10.0.0.3 from other machiens. Only 10.0.0.10 assigned to eth1 can be pinged.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? BTW, when I add on both machines the following code

```
sudo ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 dev tunnel1
sudo ip route add 10.0.2.0/24 dev tunnel1
```

then I can ssh from one to another (e.g. from B to A by ssh 10.0.2.1) so am sure that there is connectivity between the two computers, e.g. router not stopping this traffic.

I feel as I need maybe some kind of bridge between eth1 and tunnel1 or something?

Kind regards,

Pete

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (and/or 14.04).

Answer (score 0):

So, I have got it running. Turns out that MTU has to be lowered down on interfaces e.g. to 1400 so that the packets can fit into the actual packets departing from the card which has MTU 1500. Other way is to dig into splitting/assembling packet yourselves as there are some issues with GRE doing it for you ... Or OpenVPN can apparently handle it well too but I have not investigated further.